# Any WYSIWYGs that use contentEditable rather than an iframe?

Tags: wysiwyg, contenteditable, designmode

I am looking for a list of WYSIWYG editors that use contentEditable rather than a designMode iframe.

The reason I want this is that I want to have a few regions (divs) on my site that users can edit, and I want the styling (fonts, font colors, etc). to look the same in the edit area as it normally does. I don't want to have to apply a stylesheet to the WYSIWYG's iframe.

Anyone know of any light-weight, free/open-source ones?

Comment: does it need to be language agnostic or are you using one specific development language.

Comment: Needs to be for editing content in a web site--like TinyMCE. Needs to work with PHP. Pure Javascript like TinyMCE would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) uses contentEditable. YAY! THIS MAY WORK!

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but I personally feel that the [Telerik RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/editor.aspx) is hands down the best WYSIWYG around.

1. It's **not** free
2. It's .NET only
3. It allows you to style the editor to match your site exactly
4. It has some great asset management tools
5. It's super easy to configure.

Also if you can get away with a little less "fancy" I'd say that [WMD](http://wmd-editor.com/) is an awesome WYSIWY***M*** editor, and can be used across multiple development languages (It's what StackOverflow uses here on this site).

Comment: Microsoft + .NET = proprietary + costly = suck. Thanks for posting though.

Answer (score 1):

New ckeditor v4 beta has support for content-editable. http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4-beta

Answer (score 0):

Another few to throw in there, although I've never used any of them in production so can't vouch for them:

- [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/)
- [wysihtml5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/)
- [Raptor Editor](http://www.raptor-editor.com/)